# How to show Legend Color between two text in Highchart?

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

I have implemented the stacked bar Highchart. I am facing one problem while formatting the legend. I want to show the color code in between the text like

107.1TiB Color_Box data

37.2TiB Color_Box backups

Is there any way to format the legend in this way in Highchart? 
Note: I don't want to implement the custom legend. I want to play with Highchart APIs only.

[image: Highchart Problem]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `labelFormatter` function and add the color code between the series name:

```
legend: {
    rtl: true,
    labelFormatter: function() {
            var splittedName = this.name.split(' ');

        return splittedName[1] + ' ' + this.color + ' ' + splittedName[0];
    }
}
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0vatg17b/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.labelFormatter

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want legend color in between. E.g. 107TiB orange_color_box data like this

Comment: Hi @Ravi, Please check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pst9acmk/ Is this the result you wanted to achieve?